# Time average of product of two functions

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, average, fast-fourier-transform

Suppose the functions $e(x)$ and $h(x)$ with Fourier transforms $E(k)$ and $H(k)$. What is the time average A of $e(x)h(x)$ in function of their Fourier transforms $E(k)$ and $H(k)$?

My attempt:
\begin{align}
A &= \lim\limits_{X\to \infty} \frac{1}{X} \int\limits_{-X}^{X} e(x)h(x) dx \\
&= \lim\limits_{X\to \infty} \frac{1}{X} \int\limits_{-X}^{X} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} E(k)e^{ikx} dk  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(k')e^{ik'x} dk' dx \\
&=  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}E(k) H(k')\left[ \lim\limits_{X\to \infty} \frac{1}{X} \int\limits_{-X}^{X}e^{i(k+k')x} dx \right] dk dk'  \,,
\end{align}

using Wolfram Alpha
$$\lim\limits_{X\to \infty} \frac{1}{X} \int\limits_{-X}^{X}e^{i(k+k')x} dx = 0\,,$$

and thus the average $A=0$ for all functions $e(x)$ and $h(x)$... Obviously, this cannot be the case, so I have made a mistake somewhere but I cannot find it...

Comment: Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica give you *generic* values of integrals -- values that assume there is not some sneaky relationship among the parameters appearing in the integrand.  In Mathematica, you can circumbent this (usually) by setting `GenerateConditions -> True` to force explicit enumeration of assumed relationships.  Have you made WA explicitly list such relationships?  Can you think of any such relationships that might be in play?

Comment: The integral looks like a Dirac delta $\delta(k+k')$ but then there is still the $1/X$...

Comment: You're not describing a relationship among the parameters.  The parameters are $k$ and $k'$.  What interesting relations can exist between them?

Comment: Hmm, they are the same?

Comment: Is there a relation that makes $\mathrm{e}^{\text{stuff}}$ stop oscillating?

Comment: If k=-k' (as you wrote in your answer) or if k and k' are complex?

Comment: Even $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(1 + 2 \mathrm{i}) x}$ oscillates.  You probably meant when $k$ and $k'$ are (both) imaginary.  Or at least, $k+k'$ is imaginary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115620/discussion-between-fre-and-eric-towers).

Answer (score 1):

$$  \int_{-X}^{X} \; \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (k + (-k))x} \,\mathrm{d}x = 2X  \text{.}  $$